# How to mount a NRG file on Linux?

Tags: mount

I'm trying to mount an old NRG image file in my Arch Linux box. In Windows 7 I can mount it using PowerISO without problems.

When I try to mount it in Linux I get the following error messages:

```
$ sudo mount -o loop file.nrg folder/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error

In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail or so.
```

`dmesg` gives me the following output:

```
$ dmesg | tail
[103618.787063] EXT4-fs (loop0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[103618.787129] EXT4-fs (loop0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[103618.787185] EXT4-fs (loop0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[103618.788898] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
```

If I check for the file type of the image:

```
$ file file.nrg 
file.nrg: AIX core file fulldump 32-bit 64-bit
```

How can I mount this image in Linux?

Comment: It gives me the following error:
`mount: file.nrg: failed to setup loop device: Invalid argument`

Comment: "poweriso" is not available I tried "Furious ISO Mount" and it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the `poweriso` package:

`# pacman -S poweriso`

Convert the image to ISO:

`$ poweriso convert file.nrg -o file.iso`

Mount it:

`# mount file.iso folder/`

Comment: The poweriso package moved to the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/poweriso/).

Answer (score 16):

Install nrg2iso , convert and mount the iso.

Comment: I already tried, it gives the same error I described in the question.

Answer (score 9):

There is also AcetoneISO. It's covered pretty well over here in this article.

- [Mount and Unmount ISO,MDF,NRG Images Using AcetoneISO (GUI Tool)](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/mount-and-unmount-isomdfnrg-images-using-acetoneiso-gui-tool.html).
- [AcetoneISO website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/acetoneiso/)
- [AcetoneISO wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AcetoneISO)

#### Screenshot

[image: ss of acetoneiso]

#### Issues with mounting

If you get the following error:

> Error, could not mount image.

Then you most likely have an NRG file that isn't in the ISO9660 format. AcetoneISO cannot deal with these variants.

**NOTE:** See the [NRG wikipedia page for more details on this file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NRG_%28file_format%29). But I'll say it here, this is a proprietary format that the Nero Burning ROM software could write out, these aren't ISO files.

Your options become limited at this point. Under Linux you should be able to mount the `.nrg` file using a tool such as [CDex](http://cdemu.sourceforge.net/). It should be in your distro's repos. Also the [CDEmu Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDemu) has a good list of the format's it  supports and a good overview on the application.

If you need to mount/unmount these frequently this tool might also be helpful, [cdemu-tray](http://cdemu-tray.sourceforge.net/).

[image: ss of cdemu-tray]

#### iat

The [iat](http://iat.berlios.de/) tool has no switches but looks like it can convert various CDROM formats to ISO. It was available in the Ubuntu/Debian repositories. It's pretty easy to use since it has literally no command line switches.

```
iat my.nrg output.iso
```

#### FuseNRG

It's unclear whether [FuseNRG](http://fusenrg.sourceforge.net/) can deal with the non iso9660 type of NRG files. But might be worth trying. FuseNRG makes use of [fuseiso, looking at their wiki](http://fusenrg.sourceforge.net/) it's unclear there as well.

#### What else?

If none of these options work there was a method discussed in this launchpad thread titled: [Howto convert file .nrg to .iso](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/5979). The method called for using `dd` to carve out of the NRG file the actual data portion that is the contents of the ISO file. This sounded a bit drastic to me but might prove workable for you.

The #8 comment in that thread by a user named Tom Hansen gives good details on how to do this method. The method makes use of the fact noticed by him:

> it appears that an .NRG file has 300KB (75x4096) = 307200 bytes pre-pended to the ISO image.

Assuming your file has this same characteristic the method goes on like this:

```
mkdir /media/loop_cd
mount -o norock,map=off,loop,offset=307200 imagefile.nrg /media/loop_cd
```

If this works then your NRG files can be converted to ISO files, using this method:

```
dd if=imagefile.nrg of=isofile.iso bs=4096 skip=75
```

See Tom's post for more details on this technique.

Comment: I get an error when trying to mount the NRG image: `Error, could not mount image.`

Answer (score 1):

I used this when I was using Ubuntu:

```
dd bs=1k if=image.nrg of=image.iso skip=300
```

Comment: Worked for me! Just recovered some blistering funk from 2004 thanks to this!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to play an audio CD rip (from Nero, many many years ago) with this:

`mplayer -demuxer rawaudio my_audio_cd_rip.nrg`

or

`mpv -demuxer=rawaudio my_audio_cd_rip.nrg`

or (after changing the file extension)

`play -r 44100 -e signed -b 16 -c 2 -L my_audio_cd_rip.cdda`

and to convert it to an MP3:

`sox -r 44100 -e signed -b 16 -c 2 -L my_audio_cd_rip.cdda -C 320 my_audio_cd_rip.mp3`